# Batch File - Displaying specific information from command?

Tags: batch-file

If I use 'net view' in a batch file, how can I get it to ONLY display the network drives, not all the other stuff? I think I Need to use findstr...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it with

```
net view | findstr /b \\
```

Literally took me 10 seconds from when I posted this... Didn't even google, just tried it. That's luck, right?